# Table rows not deleting properly using js script in handlebars file

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I'm running a web based interface for a sql database using Node.js and handlebars. One form that I have allows users to search a table (select all national parks from a certain location). I'm using AJAX to handle forms and manipulate the tables.

I have a script in my handlebars that adds an eventListener to the submit button of the search form. Within this script, I make a POST request to run the query and return the results. Then I want to clear the table, and repopulate it with the results. Everything is working except for clearing the table. I have tried multiple methods. Each one of these methods would go in the code below where it says THIS IS WHERE THE ROWS ARE SUPPOSED TO BE CLEARED. None of the methods have worked.

Since none of these methods have worked I'm thinking the problem isn't with them itself but with some other part of my code. I've included what seems important in the code below, but I replaced the parts I know work with comments to save room.

1. Using a loop to delete rows from the table body

```
 let body = document.getElementById("park-by-location-body");
        let ct = body.childElementCount;
        for(i = 0; i < ct; i++){
          body.deleteRow(i);
        }
```

2. Setting the innerHTML of the body to an empty string

```
let body = document.getElementById("park-by-location-body");
body.innerHTML = "";
```

3. Replacing the body with a a new empty body

```
let newBody = document.createElement("tbody");
let oldBody = document.getElementById("park-by-location-body");
oldBody.parentNode.replaceChild(newBody, oldBody);
newBody.setAttribute("id", "park-by-location-body");
```

Code:

```
<form id="park-by-location-form-ajax">
    ...
</form>

<table border="1" id="parks-locations-table">
    <title> Parks </title>
    <thead>
      ...
    </thead>
    <tbody id = "park-by-location-body">
    </tbody>
</table>

<script type="application/javascript">

    // adds an event listener to the form above that sends a post and receives the results of the query
 
    populate(xhttp.response);

    // clears parks-locations table and populates with correct rows
    populate = (data) => {

        // THIS IS WHERE THE ROWS ARE SUPPOSED TO BE CLEARED

        // the rest of the script populated the data correctly
  </script>
```

Comment: I don't see Handlebars used anywhere in the code you have provided.

Comment: Also, if I was trying to remove the children of a `<tbody id="park-by-location-body">` element, I should think that `document.getElementById('park-by-location-body').innerHTML = '';` would be sufficient.

Comment: Yes I also thought that would be sufficient but apparently it is not, hence me asking the question.

Comment: It is sufficient. There must be something else you are doing that is affecting your result. For a working example, see: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/4xdwhn02/